# C# .net Web Service Web Method Returning &lt; and &gt; in View Source

Tags: c#, .net, xml, service

I have a stored procedure returning a datatable with a stored procedure in a Web Service Web Method.  I'm trying to then convert the datatable to XML, however, when I view source of the returned XML (Which looks fine in the browser window) instead of <> it's returning `&lt;` and `&gt;` around the XML nodes.

I've looked at the similar questions and I **have** tried using **HTMLEncode** or **HTMLDecode** to no avail.

Here is my Web Service Code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;

namespace DAL
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class iPhoneWebServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(Description="Return All Current Makes")]
    public string ReturnMakes()
    {
        // Get All Records with NAME Parameter
        DataTable dataTable = DataAccessLayer.ExecuteDataTable("ipa_ReturnMakes");

        StringBuilder sbrXML = new StringBuilder();

        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            sbrXML.AppendLine("<MakeList>");

            foreach (DataRow objRow in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                sbrXML.AppendLine("<Make><MakeID>[makeID]</MakeID><MakeName>[makeName]</MakeName></Make>");
                sbrXML.Replace("[makeID]", objRow["MakeID"].ToString());
                sbrXML.Replace("[makeName]", objRow["MakeName"].ToString());
            }
            sbrXML.AppendLine("</MakeList>");
        }
        else
        {
            // no data
            sbrXML.AppendLine("<makeList>");
            sbrXML.AppendLine("no data");
            sbrXML.AppendLine("</makeList>");
        }
        return sbrXML.ToString();
    }

    //Return Models From Make ID
    [WebMethod(Description="Returns Models From Make ID")]
    public string ReturnModels(int MakeID)
    {

        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("MakeID", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[0].Value = MakeID;

        // Get All Records with NAME Parameter
        DataTable dataTable = DataAccessLayer.ExecuteDataTable("ipa_ReturnModelsForMake", param);

        StringBuilder sbrXML = new StringBuilder();

        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            sbrXML.AppendLine("<ModelList>");

            foreach (DataRow objRow in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                sbrXML.AppendLine("<Model><ModelID>[modelID]</ModelID><ModelName>[modelName]</ModelName></Model>");
                sbrXML.Replace("[modelID]", objRow["ModelID"].ToString());
                sbrXML.Replace("[modelName]", objRow["ModelName"].ToString());
            }
            sbrXML.AppendLine("</ModelList>");
        }
        else
        {
            // no data
            sbrXML.AppendLine("<ModelList>");
            sbrXML.AppendLine("no data");
            sbrXML.AppendLine("</ModelList>");
        }
        return sbrXML.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

What it's returning in the view source for Web Method "ReturnModels"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">&lt;ModelList&gt;
&lt;Model&gt;&lt;ModelID&gt;20945&lt;/ModelID&gt;&lt;ModelName&gt;Anglia&lt;/ModelName&gt;&lt;/Model&gt; 
&lt;Model&gt;&lt;ModelID&gt;11006&lt;/ModelID&gt;&lt;ModelName&gt;Transit&lt;/ModelName&gt;&lt;/Model&gt;
&lt;Model&gt;&lt;ModelID&gt;21952&lt;/ModelID&gt;&lt;ModelName&gt;Zodiac Mark III&lt;/ModelName&gt;&lt;/Model&gt;
&lt;/ModelList&gt;
</string>
```

It is showing properly in the browser window:

```
<string>
<ModelList>
<Model><ModelID>20945</ModelID><ModelName>Anglia</ModelName></Model>
<Model><ModelID>15881</ModelID><ModelName>C-Max</ModelName></Model>
<Model><ModelID>20303</ModelID><ModelName>Capri</ModelName></Model>
<Model><ModelID>11006</ModelID><ModelName>Transit</ModelName></Model>
<Model><ModelID>21952</ModelID><ModelName>Zodiac Mark III</ModelName></Model>
</ModelList>
</string>
```

Just need to get what's showing in the browser window into the view source as well.

Thank you for your help and time in advance!

Comment: If you want to output XML then you should really be creating XML, not just writing it yourself.

Comment: @Prisoner You are totally right. Replace is not the way to make XML documents. Either Xelement, ToArray, ToList should be used or heaven forbid String.Format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET WebServcies use the SOAP protocol. This means that whatever information you return from your WebMethods it will automatically be placed into a SOAP envelope and XML encoded. You cannot modify the way your response is formatted as you will be violating the SOAP protocol. You shouldn't worry about what is displayed in the browser. The important thing is that this is a properly formatted XML that will be received by the client (as a string result) and could be converted to XML.

This being said what you are doing (returning string from your WebMethods representing XML) is a very bad practice as there will be a double encoding. I would recommend you defining some custom type that will represent this XML structure and return this custom type. It will make your web service easier to discover and make sense of as right now any consumer looking at the WSDL would see a method returning a string value but wouldn't know that this string represents an XML structure with some special format.

Here's what I mean:

```
public class Make
{
   public string MakeID { get; set; }
   public string MakeName { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[WebMethod(Description="Return All Current Makes")]
public Make[] ReturnMakes()
{
    // Get All Records with NAME Parameter
    DataTable dataTable = DataAccessLayer.ExecuteDataTable("ipa_ReturnMakes");
    List<Make> makes = new List<Make>();

    if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow objRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Make make = new Make
            {
                MakeID = objRow["MakeID"].ToString(),
                MakeName = objRow["MakeName"].ToString()
            };
            makes.Add (make);
        }
    }
    return makes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin I tried your above solution and all I received back was `  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <ArrayOfMake xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />`

Is this what it should return?  If so whats the simplest way to look at the XML within the SOAP?

Comment: Figured out what the problem was. Your code was missing makes.Add(make) so the list was not being populated. Once I added that, it all worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Response fixed with added missing: makes.Add (make)